# Are properties read by a Spring Property Placeholder immediately available?

Tags: java, spring

I am modifying code that uses a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in an application context file.  The properties are successfully read and used in the application.  However, if I follow the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer declaration with an `<import resource="classpath:/my/class/path/${my.file.name}" />`, a "`Could not resolve placeholder 'my.file.name'`" error and a series of exceptions are thrown.  Are properties immediately available after declaring the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?  If not, at what point do they become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple passes done on a spring context file, so it's a question of at what pass are the properties available. Unfortunately, `<import>` tags are handled on an earlier pass than bean declarations (such as the one for your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`), therefore it won't be available in the way you're trying to use it.

What you're (likely) trying to do is a common thing in Spring, with many various solutions. They often involve modifying your build to do the injection. Googling/Stack Overflowing for per-environment spring config should turn up something. I've read Spring 3.1 will provide a facility to allow per-environment configuration (so use "this" properties file if I'm doing a "test" build, this one if I'm doing a "dev" build etc.), but I don't know much about it at this point.

Comment: This is on the right track.  However, the import statement is actually reading in another context file.  My objective is to load a different context file depending on the value of my.file.name.  Each context file has a different implementation of an underlying caching mechanism, which is a bit different than merely needing to load a different properties file.  Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

Comment: The way I've done this is in the past it not to have the name of the import xml be defined by properties, but instead import "all" of the xml files and then have a property define the id of the bean to inject. So you'd import xmls which include all of your different caching mechanisms, and then the id of the one which actually gets injected (and used) is defined by a property. It's not necessarily ideal, but it does get the job done.

Comment: Does this method end up instantiating the beans in each xml, regardless of whether they are used?

Comment: @Adam it would by default yes. You could probably use `lazy-init="true"` to get around this, although I've not that used that before. It's defined in 3.4.4 of the spring documentation.

Answer (score 6):

The import resources are resolved BEFORE the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer(a BeanFactoryPostProcessor) resolves the property place holders. You will have to put the resolved resource name in your imports.

Since PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html), it is called once the bean definitions have been loaded up from the Spring configuration files.