# How to configure multiple implementations of spring application

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a legacy application and am converting it to spring.  It currently uses a static flag to do some code differently depending on the country which it has been deployed in.  For example:

```
public void myMethod() {
    //a load of code here

    if(Flags.US_BUILD == true) {
        //US Build exclusive code here
    }

    //do some more code
}
```

Intuitively my approach would be to decouple the U.S code into an interface for which the appropriate implementation get's wired in depending on whether the build is U.S or not.  I am wondering if this can be configured in my spring beans definition file (ie checking against a flag to control how things are wired), or if I am aiming at the right approach at all?

Comment: How do you set the information? During runtime or during build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Spring 3.1 Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use spring 3.1 and can't use profiles (as Ralph suggested) you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036044/221951

Comment: thanks, I neglected to mention I am migrating to use the latest version of spring