# Dynamically load a spring xml file based on database values

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

We currently have a Spring web application and are doing our configuration using XML files. We are starting Spring the DispatcherServlet which creates an XmlWebApplicationContext and loads it from the default location: spring-servlet.xml.

I am specifying several additional configuration files using the context-param contextConfigLocation. This loads up our entire application from the XML files.

So here's what I want to do. The XML file contains the database connection information and our DAOs for accessing these tables. I want to use one of those DAOs to read a value from the database and load an additional set of beans from the XML file.

So if the database value retrieved is orange, I want to load beans from orange.xml. If it's apple, I want to load apple.xml. I want these beans to be part of the same application context so after they're loaded, I can move forward without noticing the difference.

I'm wondering if I should implement my own sub-class of XmlWebApplicationContext and have DispatcherServlet implement that, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: A duplicate perhaps. Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035630/how-to-achieve-conditional-resource-import-in-a-spring-xml-context

Comment: I don't think so. The wrinkle to this is that I need to load part of the beans, then, using one of those beans, load the rest of the beans from a new XML file specified on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up extending XmlWebApplicationContext and overriding the loadBeans method. We load the beans, look up the bean that provides our configuration, then switch profiles and run again with the new profiles.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly loading from the different files, but you can try to use Spring Environment and Profile abstractions.

```
<beans profile="apple">
    <bean id="someBean">
       ...first set of bean parameters...
    </bean>
</beans>
<beans profile="orange">
    <bean id="someBean">
       ...second set of bean parameters...
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And in java:

```
context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("orange");
context.refresh();
```

Comment: If you can resolve that orange is the good profile before refresh(), then you could add directly the orange.xml config location and profiles are not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to load the configuration.

For example, if you have a LocationService that give the config locations as String[]:

```
public class XmlBeanDefinitionReaderPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory);
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        reader.setResourceLoader(new DefaultResourceLoader());
        reader.setEntityResolver(new ResourceEntityResolver(resourceLoader));
        reader.setEnvironment(new StandardEnvironment());
        LocationService locationService = (LocationService) beanFactory.getBean("locationService");

        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(locationService.getLocations());     
    }

}
```

Is not exactly the same as the reader is unaware of the already loaded beans and could be aliases or bean names colisions.

Note that your `LocationService` should not use `Autorwire`, `AOP Transactional Proxies`, and something that in general implies the use of `BeanPostProcessors`.

Other option to reuse the same `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` is overriding `postProcessBeanFactory` method in `XmlWebApplicationContext`:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext  {

    private XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader;

    @Override
    protected void loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) throws IOException {
        this.reader = reader;
        super.loadBeanDefinitions(reader);
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        LocationService locationService = (LocationService) beanFactory.getBean("locationService");
        this.reader.loadBeanDefinitions(locationService.getLocations());

        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    }

}
```