# How do I import in a spring xml conditionally

Tags: java, spring

How Do I import in a Spring based on contexts.

What i am looking for is something like

```
<import context = "x" resource="x.xml"/>
<import context = "y" resource="y.xml"/>
```

which is basically importing x or y based on some conditions.

I am using Spring 2.5.6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035630/how-to-achieve-conditional-resource-import-in-a-spring-xml-context

Comment: If you were using Spring 3.1, you could use `Profile`.