# ImportResource conditional choose of spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have spring application that is configured  by Spring annotation and I need to load complex spring xml configuration that is dependent on env system property. is it possible to do it in annotation? I need something like is in @ImportResource (it is only my idea):

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/${env:dev} == dev ? config-dev.xml : config.xml")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{

}
```

I can have these env: dev, prod, uat and I need to ensuere that for dev I will load config-dev.xml otherwise I need to load config.xml. Is it possible to do something like this in @ImportResource?

Comment: Are you using profiles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve conditional resource import in a Spring XML context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035630/how-to-achieve-conditional-resource-import-in-a-spring-xml-context)

Comment: Only way to achieve this kinda thing is to use SPEL. But since `@ImportResource` doesn't support SPEL. You want to take the approach mentioned in the link above

Comment: No, I don't use profiles :/ I will try something from the link above